# How to make an program (.exe file) visible when search from start menu

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu

I often open a program by opening Start menu and type in the, e.g. word for opening MS Word. But sometimes there are programs that do not need to install and just run directly from disk, e.g. ZoomIt, Tail, UniKey ... These program can not be found from Start Menu.

I try to copy the program folder to C:\Program Files but it doesn't help :) and I gave up. Please help if you know how to do it.

Comment: Did that answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would right click on the EXE, hit Create Shortcut, THEN drag the shortcut to the start menu.  Just to be safe.  Can't always count on Windows handling that kinda stuff intelligently...

You can drag it right to the Start Button, hover there for a second and the menu will pop up.  hovering over All Programs will have the same effect.  Place as needed, and at that point you should be able to search for it.  Right click on it in the start menu and click rename  if you didn't rename it before you moved it.

Comment: Much better way to do it than dragging the actual program into the start menu

Comment: Oops, this is what I meant to write, haha I forgot the "create shortcut" part. xD My bad. +1