# Win 10: How to make exe appear in search results

Tags: windows-10, search, start-menu

I basically want to do this, but in Windows 10: [How to make an program (.exe file) visible when search from start menu](https://superuser.com/questions/172241/how-to-make-an-program-exe-file-visible-when-search-from-start-menu) (I've tried the solution listed there, but it doesn't seem to work in Windows 10)

I have an exe that I would like to be able to search for by pressing the windows key/start button. How can I make this exe show up in start menu search results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to add something to the start menu is to do this:

1. Right-click on your `.EXE` file and select `Create shortcut`.
2. Open `Run...` and type `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and press `OK`.
3. Drag and drop the shortcut to your `.EXE` file into the Windows Explorer window you opened in Step 2.
4. Right-click the shortcut to your `.EXE` file and select `Rename...` if you wish to change the name to something more user-friendly.

That shortcut should now appear in the Start Menu.  Don't forget, you can also do this with documents and files, such as `.DOCX` or `.JPG` files if you use them frequently.

Hope this helped...

Comment: That was it! It's unfortunate that they removed the easy functionality, but I guess I'll just make a shortcut in my start menu to access the start menu folder. >.>

Comment: You could theoretically write a plug-in to add the option 'Add to Start Menu' to the right-click context menu, but that's beyond my capabilities.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore apparently.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution for `.exe` files on windows 10 (Windows 10 pro).

- Right-click the `.exe` file, click `pin to start` option from the menu. That's it :)
  [image: right click menu image]
  (A right-click on the file after this will give you an unpin from start option)